# setup:di:compile and changing mode to production fails in Magento 2

Tags: php, magento, magento2

When I try to change mode from developer to production a non-zero exit code is returned. I figured out it was not during deployment of static content, it was during compilation. `memory_limit` is 2000M. I checked `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` and found out that it stops and exits compilation at `Repositories code generation...` without showing any error. I migrated the site to localhost, and now it successfully compiles and goes to production mode.

Why is it working in localhost, but fails in the online server?

Comment: Do you have any code?

Answer (score 3):

Open admin : store> configuration > Advanced > Developer >Frontend Development Workflow > Workflow type > Server Side less compilation then

Use below commonds for set production mode.

```
rm -rf var/*
rm -rf pub/static/*
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production --skip-compilation
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
chmod -R 7777 var pub/static
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi use this command to deploy when getting memory-limit problem.

php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy